# Spreading an iterable ...obj[Symbol.iterator](...)

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator

I understand most of the following code, but I'm completely stuck on `[...numbers[Symbol.iterator]`.

```
var numbers = {
    *[Symbol.iterator]({
        start = 0,
        stop = 100,
        step = 1
    } = {}) {
        for(let x = start; x <= stop; x+=step) {
            yield x;
        }
    }
};

// should print 0.. 100 in steps of 1
for(let num of numbers) {
    console.log(num);
}

// should print 6..30 in steps of 4
console.log(`My lucky numbers are: ${
    [...numbers[Symbol.iterator]({
        start: 6,
        stop: 30,
        step: 4
    })]}`
);
```

In my mind:

If it was just `[...numbers]` it would spread the numbers 0 - 100 because the object has an iterator function/generator.
If it was just `numbers[Symbol.iterator]()` it would look up and return the generator.

But I've no clue with `[...numbers[Symbol.iterator](...)`, which looks like a strange combination of the two.

I'm struggling to get results when googling this syntax. If anyone could explain it like I'm 5 that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really weird usage of `Symbol.iterator`, you normally shouldn't give them parameters. You can pull it apart into

```
const generatorFunction = numbers[Symbol.iterator];
const iterator = generatorFunction({
    start: 6,
    stop: 30,
    step: 4
});
const array = [...iterator];
console.log(`My lucky numbers are: ${array}`);
```

Notice that `iterator` is iterable, it inherits a `[Symbol.iterator]` method returning itself, which allows it to be used in the array spread element. That the generator method (which is called explicitly here) is named `[Symbol.iterator]` as well doesn't matter, it only leads to confusing. A more better style to write this would be

```
const numbers = {
    *range(start, stop, step=1) {
        for(let x = start; x <= stop; x+=step) {
            yield x;
        }
    },
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this.range(0, 100);
    },
};

console.log([...numbers.range(6, 30, 4)]);
```

Comment: I think I might have understood the specific line. Does ...numbers spread to an array first? So it looks like this: [1,2,3,4][Symbol.iterator]({ params }) which is effectively searching for and then calling the array's Symbol.iterator function?

Comment: although thinking about it that makes no sense either, because the parameters passed are for the numbers object iterator. Your answer is helpful though Bergi, thanks (I deleted an earlier reply), but the original specific syntax still just isn't clicking with me.

Comment: "*Does ...numbers spread to an array first?*" - no, the function call is one expression. It evaluates to the generator, which is then spread into the array. You can also write `[... (numbers[Symbol.iterator](…)) ]`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't originally understand the first half of Bergi's answer

It became clear (for my brain at least) when viewed as leaving the spread operator until last, which to be fair is exactly what he explained, but I couldn't see it.

Anyway:

`[numbers[Symbol.iterator]({...})]` returns the generator, which is **then** spread.